# SQL Server Reporting Services Data Extention

Tags: reportingservices-2005

So... here's my story:

I'm trying to create a SQL server data extension (to be precise, I'm trying to get some sample code to run) (SSRS2005).

I've done the following:

1. Placed the extension assembly into the ReportServer/bin folder.
2. Placed the assembly into the Private Assemblies folder.
3. Modified rsreportserver.config in, and added the assembly info to the data section.
4. Modified rssrvpolicy.config, and added a code group for the assembly with Full Trust.
5. Modified RSReportDesigner.config in PrivateAssemblies. Added the assembly to the data and the designer sections, specifying the generic query designer.
6. Modified RSPreviewPolicy.config. Added the assembly with Full Trust.

The new Data Source type is available for selection, but when I try to view the dataset I get this error: The data extension DataSet could not be loaded.  Check the configuration file RSReportDesigner.config.

The location of the assembly is configured properly (I think), because I've added logging code and I can see that the constructor of the Connection object is being called.

In fact, I've added logging code to every method of every class in the assembly, and as far as I can tell the failure occurs right after the connection object's constructor is called.

Any ideas on how I might proceed to debug this?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem:

Every SSRS data extension sample project I found came along with a copy of Microsoft.Reporting.Interfaces.dll. It turned out that they copy they came with was different from the copy in my private assemblies and bin folders. When I referenced the assembly present in 'private assemblies' and recompiled it started to work.

So... this question is answered, but it brings up another problem.

At some point this extension needs to be delivered to a customer, so what do I do about the potential assembly version difference?

Is it a matter of requiring a certain service pack?
Is it safe to just replace the existing version with whatever version the custom data extension uses?